# What is the correct way to insert an Array of INET type in Postgresql using Python ( psycopg2 library )

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I've gotten this error consistently while trying to insert to an array of INET type.

`psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type inet: "Inet('8.8.8.8')"`

Also for some variants I've tried:

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Test table:

```
cursor.execute( "CREATE TABLE test( ip_list inet[] );" )
```

Some variants I've tried to get it to work:

```
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", ( str( { "8.8.8.8" } ) ) )
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", ( str( { psycopg2.extras.Inet( "8.8.8.8" ) } ) ) )
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", ( psycopg2.extras.Inet( [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ] ) ) )
```

The `psycopg2.extras.Inet( [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ] )` command generates the correct Inet object `Inet(['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4'])`.

However while trying to insert using that with

```
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", ( psycopg2.extras.Inet( [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ] ) ) )
```

It gives me the error: `TypeError: 'Inet' object does not support indexing`

When I tried casting it to string before inserting via:

```
ursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", ( str( psycopg2.extras.Inet( [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ] ) ) ) )
```

I got the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Comment: If you're inserting into an array field, shouldn't the insert value be something like `array['8.8.8.8']::inet[]`?

Comment: Per the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#networking-data-types), it looks like psycopg will cast array of inet to a list of strings. However, I'm not too sure how it works the other way around. Maybe you can try `cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );", (['8.8.8.8'],))` for a parametrized insert.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr that line gives the error `DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

Comment: @MeghdeepRay: Using sqlfiddle, this worked. `INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES
('{ 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4}');`. What you need is curly braces to indicate an array. Surround it with quotes to make it a single string. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) is the doc that explains how to use arrays.

Comment: @shahkalpesh That is definitely working but I need it to work with parameterised inputs.

Comment: @MeghdeepRay: `cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO test( ip_list ) VALUES ('{ 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4}')");` - does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in how you format the string and the syntax of your query.

You can simply insert a record if you run your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO itest( ip_list ) VALUES ( '{ 8.8.8.8 }' );
```

Or multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO itest( ip_list ) VALUES ('{ 192.168.2.1, 120.12.25.26, 10.20.30.40, 156.223.122.252 }');
```

.

To format the query like this in python, you can do something like this:

```
cur.execute( "INSERT INTO itest( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s );" % ("'{ 200.8.8.200 }'"))
```

.

===============================================================

## Edit:

Answer to the comment:

I just looked at the `Inet()` class and it doesn't seem to be returning the proper casting for arrays (I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here, correct me if I'm wrong). However, as a workaround, I came up with this.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute( "INSERT INTO itest( ip_list ) VALUES ( %s[] );", (Inet([ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ]),))
conn.commit()
```

As you can see, I have manually added the array casting `[]` to the `inet` type.

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts!!

Comment: How is this accomplished with parameterized input via the psycopg2 library ? If I have to input a variable number of IPs each time ?

Comment: @MeghdeepRay please see the edit part of my answer. I updated it.